# Close Case after two days Milestone is completed

Tags: casemilestone

Im having issue with Case Milestones. I have two Milestones for cases, Reaction time and Resolution time.

I have set milestones to mark as completed when case status is marked as closed. But team is marking milestones completed manually and sometimes case is not marked as completed even case has been resolved. So they wanted that Case would close automatically after two days Resolution time is completed.

I have search this issue a lot and I haven´t find solution. Have anyone had similar problem or have in mind solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Do you have triggers built to change the record status when a milestone is reached?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [scheduled flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5) with an action that closes the case.